# installed matplotlib in virtenv successfully, but can not import it

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

I have installed matplotlib successfully on python 3.7 in a virtual environment:

1. `activate virtenv`
2. `pip install matplotlib`

When I use python shell in `cmd`, `import matplotlib` works well. But I can not import it in `jupyter notebook`

Can someone help?

Comment: Classic error: your `jupyter notebook` is not using the `python` from your virtual env

Comment: Does it mean, I can not use jupyter Notebook with virtenv?

Comment: No, but you need to configure the kernel correctly, see the link posted by Philip in the comments to his answer

Comment: Install Jupyter in your venv